# Angular: How to Get Private Methods into Code Coverage?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular8

Is there anyway to add Private Methods from `ng test --code-coverage` into Code Coverage Reports in Angular 8?

Our Ng TestCode Coverage is low percentage, since its checking private methods.

According to articles, private methods should not require unit testing. Only the Public methods, which call private methods need to.

*Reading about tags; if any method is prefixed with `public`, it should be unit tested. Team can also start placing `private` before methods. Would this method allow ng test to find what requires testing?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

[https://anthonysciamanna.com/2016/02/14/should-private-methods-be-tested.html#:~:text=Unit%20Tests%20Should%20Only%20Test,are%20dependent%20on%20the%20object](https://anthonysciamanna.com/2016/02/14/should-private-methods-be-tested.html#:%7E:text=Unit%20Tests%20Should%20Only%20Test,are%20dependent%20on%20the%20object).
[image]

Currently testing Typescript in Angular 8.

Comment: .... or typically no prefix (which defaults to private in Typescript).

No mate.. You understood 1 thing wrong. Default access modifier in typescript is Public.

Comment: Yup. But still Private Methods are considered for code coverage.

Nothing to worry, the ngOnInit is called when component gets initialized and there after you can chain all your private methods for coverage

Comment: You can read more about TS access modifiers here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-by-default

Happy coding mate :)

Comment: If a private method is called via a HTML event say button click, you will need to access the dom element through By.css method and click() it from your tests

Comment: If a private method is getting called from a public method, then you'll need to call the public method from tests and ensure the private method gets called through the code flow.

Comment: Let me furnish an answer with details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code coverage checks for private methods too.

Generally, there are 2 scenarios where private method gets called.

- If private method gets called inside a public method (directly or if satisfies any condition)

> For this case, you will need to call the public method in your tests and cover the underlying private method directly and satisfying the condition from your tests.

- If the private method gets called from a DOM event say button click

> For this case, you will need to capture the button using [By.css](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By) and fire click event.

Note :: Till Angular ivy got introduced, we could bind button click event to private method in TS class but from now on its not possible. It will give compilation error.

`Property 'onClickMethod' is private and only accessible within class 'AppComponent'`

Answer (score 2):

I am adding few more points to the answer explained above by Akhil.

1. I see ternary operations used in your code. Make sure you are writing test cases to cover all scenarios. (Negative, Positive or based on some specific value). Same goes for all conditional things you are going to do in your code.
2. Once you run your test cases make sure you are opening developer tools and debug the actual process. This is because sometimes your code will give exception but still your test case will pass. In this case most of the lines after exceptions will not be covered.

Always make sure there is no console error in your test case run also. Chrome debugger tool should be on priority.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Agreed.. To cover all the statements and blocks we'll need to write tests for erroneous cases too..  thanks Ankit for bringing up this point.